# Webmatrix crashes when site is opened or created

Tags: webmatrix

When I open WebMatrix it works without problem and shows the start page.
When I click 'My sites' and choose my site or choose My site by click 'Open'=> My site or create new site (and choose the site type: Empty, App Gallery or Template Gallery) WebMatrix crashes. Note: It crashes when it needs to show the site pages.

I tried to re-install WebMatrix but that didn't help. I also tried to change the Workspace(by clicking 'Options' on the start page).

When it crashes, I get the message 'Windows is looking for a solution to the problem.' (My computer isn't in English so that might not exactly be the words) and then I am asked if I want to close/debug the program. I click 'Debug' and choose Visual Studio. I don't know how to debug a program, but I tried and it says to me that:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Microsoft.WebMatrix.Core.dll
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object [-translated].
```

I have searched on the internet and here and I didn't find any solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Actual Answer

This bug is in the market for a time now. I have seen similar issue on another forum too, where the user was facing the same issue and same thing he tried but all in vain.

I think you need to wait for the next Update for your System, or try removing each and every component that WebMatrix installed, that means all the .NET Frameworks (4th version), Sql Dependencies Sql Server Ce, and all other files that were shipped along with WebMatrix to your computer. Remove them, and start the installing process once again freshly.

If nothing does the job, please uninstall WebMatrix 3 and install WebMatrix 2: [Click here for link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/5/7/8573745C-384B-4F74-BE2C-D85C390742D5/WebMatrix_x86_en-US.msi). I know it is awkward to go back a version, but you'll have to. Secondly you can mention this bug on their support/suggestion page. They would fix it.

http://webmatrix.uservoice.com/

I hope that would help you. And you'd be back in developing the apps :-)

#### Just for information

Secondly, do you understand what is meant by **debug**? Debugging is a method or process to remove the bugs from a software or an application etc. When you chose Visual Studio, it provided you or not provided you with the WebMatrix source code, I am not sure I never tried it. And you tried out debugging it. The exception is gave you, was a message saying that the parameter you're passing onto the next stage is a `null`. Which means it doesn't even exist and thus the value or the method cannot be executed and it breaks.